# Issue fitting multiple keras Sequential models in the same python script

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Please see gist [here](https://gist.github.com/rindis/c125deda8e0deec02838c3732de154e8) for the full code. In this question I've pasted what I regard the important part of the code at the bottom.

First I generate a dataset as shown in [[2](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5656074/104932424-e6b58b80-59a7-11eb-8638-7c225a44db8f.png)], which consists of 2 features (`x` and `y`) and 3 labels (`grey`, `blue` and `orange`). Then I make 4 keras sequential models with identical layer structure, optimizer, loss function, etc. Lastly, I call `fit` on each model and plot the resulting metrics shown in [[3](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5656074/104932426-e74e2200-59a7-11eb-84c0-94187b198545.png)]. As you can see the models all perform differently and I'm wondering why? I've locked the random seed value so each time I run this script I get the exact same result.

In this example the models have identical structures, so I would expect the metric plots to be identical. Eventually I would like to vary the number of layers, layer size, loss function, etc. between the models to see its effects, but that does not seem feasible in this setup. Am I approaching this incorrectly?

An interesting thing to note is that by setting the `batch_size` to 32 this effect is not as prominent, but it is still present and reproducible (See [[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pFOc.png)]).

[image: Data]

[image: Metrics]

[image: Metrics with batch_size=32]

```py
# ---- MAKE MODELS ---- #
NUMBER_OF_MODELS = 4
models = []
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_MODELS):
    model = keras.models.Sequential(name=f'{i}')

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu', input_shape=df_train['features'].values.shape[-1:]))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])

    model.summary()
    models.append(model)
# --------------------- #

# ---- TRAIN MODELS ---- #
histories = []
for model in models:
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        history = model.fit(x=df_train['features'].values, y=df_train['labels'].values,
                            validation_data=(df_val['features'].values, df_val['labels'].values),
                            batch_size=512, epochs=100, verbose=0)
        histories.append(history)
# ---------------------- #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply need to set the seed every time you define and fit the model

following your code I collapse all in these lines:

```
NUMBER_OF_MODELS = 4
models = []
histories = []

for i in range(NUMBER_OF_MODELS):

    set_seed_TF2(33)

    model = keras.models.Sequential(name=f'{i}')

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu', input_shape=df_train['features'].values.shape[-1:]))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
    
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        
        history = model.fit(x=df_train['features'].values, y=df_train['labels'].values,
                            validation_data=(df_val['features'].values, df_val['labels'].values),
                            batch_size=512, epochs=100, verbose=0)
        histories.append(history)
        
    models.append(model)
```

the magic function is `set_seed_TF2`

```
def set_seed_TF2(seed):
    
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
```

that must be call every time you initialize the model and fit

with this in mind, you can produce every time the same metrics/predictions:

[image]

here the running notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nHEDI6d3LsRPQUXGiTOYfNOfw954Pu-H?usp=sharing

**this works for CPU only**

Comment: Oh ok, that is interesting! Why is it like this? Do you HAVE to do it sequentially like that? So, `set_seed` -> `compile` -> `fit`, sequentially for each model? Or is it possible to first compile all the models in one loop, and then fit all the models in another loop?

Comment: every time you initialize a model, new random weights are generated like every random operation in python. for sure in this order works. if you want to first compile and then fit you can try... but in the compile loop I suggest to do set_seed(X)->compile while in the fit loop set_seed(X)->fit every time you compute a compile/fit (like in the example I provided u)... don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)

Comment: But the seeds have already been set at the beginning. Are they somehow invalidated when a keras model is initialized?

Comment: if you do: np.random.seed(0); X = np.random.uniform(0,1,10); Y = np.random.uniform(0,1,10)... X is different from Y, it's the same logic